# GcmReceiver cannot get any messages with payload having the field "message_type"

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

It's my understanding that the payload can have any field names, but look like that is not the case. In the following code, if jData has a field "message_type", the android app will not receive a push notification for the message even sending the message to GCM succeeds (receiving a response: {"message_id":xxx}). I guess somehow "message_type" is used internally by GCM, so we should never use that field?

```
jGcmData.put("to", "/topics/global");

// What to send in GCM message.
jGcmData.put("data", jData);

// Create connection to send GCM Message request.
URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty(
      "Authorization", "key=" + mContext.getString(R.string.google_server_api_key));
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As talked about on [GCM Reference](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#downstream-xmpp-messages-json)

> **data    Optional, JSON object**
>
> .......
>
> The key should not be a reserved word ("from" or any word starting
>   with "google" or "gcm"). **Do not use any of the words defined in this
>   table** (such as collapse_key).

On reference for [Downstream message XMPP message response body](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#notification-payload-support)

> **message_type     Required, string**
>
> This parameter specifies an 'ack' or
>   'nack' message from the XMPP connection server to the app server.
>
> If the value is set to nack, the app server should look at error and
>   error_description to get failure information.

***message_type is defined in reference table so it is a reserved word.***

So

### Do not use it.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the http protocol, so I guess  this is the correct doc: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref. This does not have message_type. Probably a bug in GCM's internal implementation.

Comment: Maybe there is a bug or maybe xmpp and http have same(shared) filter to check these rules